# Can I create an array that works in ngStyle or ngClass?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to change the colors of some letters in HTML and need them to change depending on a piece of veritable information. They change based off one variable information, but I would like to add more variables to the same color option so I need an array.
Essentially I have average1, average2, and colorOption. If average1 is less than 50 it will be red, but if average2 is greater than 100 it will change to red.

here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  <canvas 
  class="offset"
  id="Chart4" 
  width="240"
  height="180" 
  ></canvas> 

  <h1 class = "fontStyleHole">
    <h1 [ngStyle]="{'color': colorOption}">
      {{averag1}}
    </h1>
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <canvas 
  class="offset"
  id="Chart5" 
  width="240"
  height="180" 
  ></canvas> 

  <h1 class = "fontStyleHole">
    <h1 [ngStyle]="{'color': colorOption}">
      {{average2}}
    </h1>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**TypeScript Current:**

```
if(this.average2 >= 55){            
  this.colorOption="#FF2A00"
}
else if(this.average2 >= 50){
  this.colorOption='#EB9E00'
}
else if(this.average2 >=45){
  this.colorOption="#C6EB00"
}
else{
  this.colorOption='#04FF00'
}

if(this.average1 >= 280){

  this.colorOption="#FF2A00"
}
else if(this.average1 >= 250){

  this.colorOption='#EB9E00'
}
else if(this.average1 >=220){
  this.colorOption="#C6EB00"
}
else{
  this.colorOption='#04FF00'
}
```

**Typescript That I want:**

```
    if(this.Classyaverage >= 55){            
  this.colorOption[1]="#FF2A00"
}
else if(this.Classyaverage >= 50){
  this.colorOption[1]='#EB9E00'
}
else if(this.Classyaverage >=45){
  this.colorOption[1]="#C6EB00"
}
else{
  this.colorOption[1]='#04FF00'
}

if(this.average1 >= 280){

  this.colorOption[2]="#FF2A00"
}
else if(this.average1 >= 250){

  this.colorOption[2]='#EB9E00'
}
else if(this.average1 >=220){
  this.colorOption[2]="#C6EB00"
}
else{
  this.colorOption[2]='#04FF00'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a styling problem, so maybe you should try a styling solution.
It would be easier to apply a class dynamically than to calculate DOM style property values explicitly.

component.html:

```
 <h1 [ngClass]="{
  'color-blue': condition,
  'color-green': !condition,
  'color-yellow': condition && anotherCondition,
  }>
```

component stylesheet:

```
.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}
.color-green {
  color: green;
}
etc...
```

Bonus blog post from a credible author:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ng-class-angular-classes

Comment: Ok, that kinda makes sense but why are you putting HTML into ts? and at what point does this ts reach the HTML?

Comment: You got me. I mislabeled.

Comment: Ok... then how do you do conditions in HTML I thought it's language didn't allow that. (I'm new to HTML if you can't tell)

Comment: @SilasBazar normally you cannot but Angular considers the html files to be part of a component. It therefore supplies a template syntax. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax